# How work autocomplete multiple id's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How work autocomplete multiple id's?
autocomplete work on first Input: Name but not work on second Input: Type

Jquery Code:

```
$(function() {

    $("#tags_1").autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/bizaccount/check",
        minLength: 1,
    });

});
```

html code:

```
<td><input id="tags" name="name" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input id="tags" name="type" type="text" value=""></td>
```

any solution?

Comment: Your question isn't clear and your code isn't complete. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 1):

It appear that your jQuery selector based on ID of the element, change it to class like `.tags` because browser usually only considers first element with same id, but for class it will consider all elements.

```
$(".tags").autocomplete({
        source: "Check",
        minLength: 1,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 elements with the same id, it's not valid and won't work as id selectors never process more than one element.

You should use css classes and call autocomplete using `.tags` selector.

```
$(".tags").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/bizaccount/check",
    minLength: 1,
});

<td><input class="tags" name="name" type="text" value=""></td>
<td><input class="tags" name="type" type="text" value=""></td>
```